# css shape-outside not working

Tags: css, css-shapes

See this [code-pen](https://codepen.io/martellalex/pen/EKEzwm):

```css
* {
  min-height: 100%
}
#image-sculptor {
  display: block;
  height: 321px;
  width: 600px;
}
#image-sculptor-overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-size: cover!important;
  -webkit-shape-outside: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blog.cherysh/2016/Apr/sculptingOutline-1460706451344.png');
}
#text-sculptor {
  position: absolute!important;
  right: 60%;
  bottom: -15%;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<container>
  <div id="image-sculptor" style="background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blog.cherysh/2016/Apr/sculpting-1460436288043.jpeg);background-size:cover">
    <div id="image-sculptor-overlay" sytle="background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blog.cherysh/2016/Apr/sculptingOutline-1460705174245.png)">
    </div>
    <div id="text-sculptor" font-to-height="0.1" line-height-ratio="1"><span>"The essence of all art is to have pleasure in giving pleasure"<br>-Dale Carnegie</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</container>
```

I'm trying to get css `shape-outside` to draw the text in the div to the right of the sculpture in the image.

Have been trying for a few hours with no joy.

Comment: You have CORS errors ... Probably it's paranoid on the browsers side, but using an image for shape outside is not allowed if the image is not from the same origin

Comment: Also anyone new to "shape-outside": Notice that it creates __invisible layers__.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach would be to use the `polygon()` value for the [shape-outside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) property.

*Note that you also need to float the element with the shape-outside property and not position the text absolutely*

Here is an example:

```css
#image-sculptor {
  display: block;
  height: 321px;
  width: 600px;
}
#image-sculptor-overlay {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%, 68% 0%, 74% 15%, 70% 50%);
          shape-outside: polygon(100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 0%, 68% 0%, 74% 15%, 70% 50%);
}
```

```html
<container>
  <div id="image-sculptor" style="background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blog.cherysh/2016/Apr/sculpting-1460436288043.jpeg);background-size:cover">
    <div id="image-sculptor-overlay" sytle="background:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blog.cherysh/2016/Apr/sculptingOutline-1460705174245.png)">
    </div>
    <div id="text-sculptor" font-to-height="0.1" line-height-ratio="1"><span>"The essence of all art is to have pleasure in giving pleasure""The essence of all art is to have pleasure in giving pleasure""The essence of all art is to have pleasure in giving pleasure" "The essence of all art is to have, "The essence of all art is to have "The essence of<br>-Dale Carnegie</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</container>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, that worked a treat.  Did you just eyeball the polygon coordinates?

Comment: You can use the mozilla debug tool to get the polygon coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

The image you are using ([link](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/blog.cherysh/2016/Apr/sculptingOutline-1460706451344.png)) doesn't have any transparency. Try creating the image that is transparent instead of white (like [this one](http://codropspz.tympanus.netdna-cdn.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/bear-shape.png) which comes from [this article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/shape-outside/) on the matter).